# Кастомные mapkit annotation image

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

Необходимо а зависимости от типа пина (тип1, тип2 и тип3) ненести на PinAnnotationView определенную картинку.

Пробывал создавать аннотацию таким способом

```
//Создание первой аннотации--------------------------------
AnnotationMap* annotation = [[AnnotationMap alloc] init];

annotation.title = @"Test Title";
annotation.subtitle = @"Test subtitle";
annotation.type = @"type1";
annotation.coordinate = self.mapView.region.center;
[self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];

//Создание второй аннотации-------------------------------
AnnotationMap* annotation1 = [[AnnotationMap alloc] init];

annotation1.title = @"Test Title";
annotation1.subtitle = @"Test subtitle";
annotation1.type = @"type2";
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
coord.latitude = 55.73850322752935;
coord.longitude = 37.59373962879181;
annotation1.coordinate = coord;
[self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation1];
```

(тип аннотации создал вручную в проперти класса AnnotationMap)

```
[self.mapView addAnnotation:mapAnnotation];
```

После этого не знаю как внедрить логику что бы картинка грузилась именно того типа которого нужно.

Вот реализация загрузки аннотации с картинкой (картинка почему то тоже не загружается...)

```
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
    return nil;
}

static NSString* identifier = @"Annotation";

MKPinAnnotationView* pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView*)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

if (!pinView) {

    NSString * type1 = @"type1"; //Первый тип
    NSString * type2 = @"type2"; //Второй тип
    NSString * type3 = @"type3"; //Третий тип


    AnnotationMap * typeAnnotation = [[AnnotationMap alloc] init];

    if (typeAnnotation.type == type1) {

        pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
        UIImage *pinImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"type1.png"];
        [pinView setImage:pinImage];
    }

    else
    {
        pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
        UIImage *pinImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"type2.png"];
        [pinView setImage:pinImage];
    }


}

else {
    pinView.annotation = annotation;
    pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
}

return pinView;
```

//---------------------------------------------------------

```
MKPinAnnotationView *annView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"ParkingPin"];

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrest"]];

annView.animatesDrop = TRUE;
annView.canShowCallout = YES;
annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5);
[annView addSubview:imageView];
return annView;
```

Нашел решение первой проблемы добавляя не UIImage а UIImageVie
Но после этого происходит наложение изображения кастомного пина на стандартную картинку пина...

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

//Всё сделал, не очень грамотно, просто закрыл кастомной картинкой основную, но анимации не буду использовать, так что никто об это ни кто не узнает, с разными картинками тоже всё вышло, высылаю ответ.

```
if (![annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {

MKPinAnnotationView *annView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"ParkingPin"];
NSString * imageName = @"clear.png";
annView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];

    NSString * type1 = @"type1";
    NSString * type2 = @"type2";

    AnnotationMap * annotationTest = (AnnotationMap*)annotation;
    if (annotationTest.type == type1) {

        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bluePin.png"]];
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(-5, -5, 30, 50);

        annView.animatesDrop = TRUE;
        annView.canShowCallout = YES;
        annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
        [annView addSubview:imageView];

        return annView;
    }

    else if (annotationTest.type == type2) {

        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"brownPin.png"]];
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(-5, -5, 30, 50);

        annView.animatesDrop = TRUE;
        annView.canShowCallout = YES;
        annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
        [annView addSubview:imageView];

        return annView;

    }

    else {

        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greenPin.png"]];
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(-5, -5, 30, 50);

        annView.animatesDrop = TRUE;
        annView.canShowCallout = YES;
        annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
        [annView addSubview:imageView];

        return annView;

    }
}

else
{
    return nil;
}
```

}

Comment: Если вы говорите, что картинка не грузится, может с нее начать? я бы предложил убрать `.png` в присвоении.

Comment: if (!pinView)  - а не в этом ли проблемма, просто выше вы создаете этот самый pinView а ниже проверяете, если его нет, то...

Comment: у меня три типа к сожалению, просто один не прописал...

Comment: Max Mikheyenko, согласен с вами, по пробывал без png, ситуация не изменилась ((

Comment: так на карте появляется что- то но без картинки, или вообще ничего?

Comment: после некоторого гугления, я думаю проблема в том, что вам надо использовать `MKAnnotationView`, поскольку `MKPinAnnotationView` предполагает, что вы не хотите использовать кастомную картинку, а хотите использовать имеено пин. Сейчас проверю отпишусь.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Как я уже указал в комментарии: в iOS9 эпл ужесточил правила для `MKAnnotationView`. В частности  `MKPinAnnotationView` больше не показывает кастомные изображения, а реагирует только на изменение цвета - `pinTintColor`.

Чтобы показать кастомное изображение используйте `MKAnnotationView`.

```
MKAnnotationView *annView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"ParkingPin"];
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь !!